# Python SQLAlchemy Database Migrations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

What is the correct way to handle database migrations in SQL Alchemy? If I update the ORM class will the underlying table get updated by itself? What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with Flask, so I assume you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy. If that's the case, take a look at [Flask-Migrate](http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a Flask extension that wraps Alembic.

Alembic is a database migration tool written by the author of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: yes i am using flask and sql aclhemy together